# Delete multiple items in one array in react state from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this array

```
let deleted = [
  {id: '123', name: 'Something'},
  {id: '321', name: 'Something1'}
];
```

and I have this

```
this.setState({
            config: {
                ...this.state.config,
                categories: this.state.config.categories.map(cat => ({
                    ...cat,
                    movies: [...cat.movies, ...currentMovies]
                }))
            }
        });
```

Every movies array for every category contains all items from `deleted` array but are not the same arrays because some contains selected property and some not, but movie id's are the same.

How can I delete every item from delete array from every categories.movies array?

I am thinking to iterate through deleted and then for every item in that array do

```
movies: this.state.config.categories.filter(item => item.id !== deleted.id)
```

But i do not know if that's a best solution, can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show all of your data structures as a [mcve] to eliminate ambiguity and guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. filter the movies as well with map.

```
const filt = (item) => item.id !== deleted.id;
this.state.config.categories.filter(filt).map(({ movies, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  movies: movies.filter(filt),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what the state structure is, but to filter the movies array by checking against an array of movies to delete can be done a couple ways using an array::filter function.

1. Search the deleted array each iteration and check if the movie id's match (*`O(n)` linear search*). If no match found then include in the result.

```
movies.filter(movie => !deleted.some(({ id }) => movie.id === id))
```

```js
let deleted = [
  { id: "123", name: "Something" },
  { id: "321", name: "Something1" }
];

const currentState = {
  movies: [
    { id: "120", name: "Something 120" },
    { id: "121", name: "Something 121" },
    { id: "122", name: "Something 122" },
    { id: "123", name: "Something" },
    { id: "124", name: "Something 124" },
    { id: "125", name: "Something 125" },
    { id: "321", name: "Something1" }
  ]
};

const nextState = currentState.movies.filter(
  movie => !deleted.some(({ id }) => movie.id === id)
);

console.log(nextState)
```

2. Create a map of deleted movie ids so you don't have to search each time (*`O(1)` constant-time search*).

```
const deletedMovieIdSet = deleted.reduce((ids, { id }) => {
  ids.add(id);
  return ids;
}, new Set());

...

movies.filter(movie => !deletedMovieIdSet.has(movie.id))
```

```js
let deleted = [
  { id: "123", name: "Something" },
  { id: "321", name: "Something1" }
];

const deletedMovieIdSet = deleted.reduce((ids, { id }) => {
  ids.add(id);
  return ids;
}, new Set());

const currentState = {
  movies: [
    { id: "120", name: "Something 120" },
    { id: "121", name: "Something 121" },
    { id: "122", name: "Something 122" },
    { id: "123", name: "Something" },
    { id: "124", name: "Something 124" },
    { id: "125", name: "Something 125" },
    { id: "321", name: "Something1" }
  ]
};

const nextState = currentState.movies.filter(
  movie => !deletedMovieIdSet.has(movie.id)
);

console.log(nextState)
```